# Real time dynamic map software

Tags: maps, real-time

I want to develop a real time dynamic map. I have geopositioned alerts, geopositioned data and I would like to show these inputs on a 3D map with drawn building outline (i.e. not the ones from Google Maps). It should look like the coolmaps from Esri https://coolmaps.esri.com/#12 but preferably open source or, at least, not so expensive as the Esri software.

Any suggestion?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Depending upon your end user base, the assumption being broader user base.

You could try using Blender - you will need to download some plugins, (GIS plugin) and go from there!
A quick how to article is here.
Note you may need some desktop software to process your data beforehand.

[https://wesleybarrgis.wordpress.com/2020/05/19/how-to-make-a-3d-map-in-blender/#:~:text=%20How%20to%20Make%20a%203D%20Map%20in,quality%20until%20the%20final%20images%20are...%20More%20](https://wesleybarrgis.wordpress.com/2020/05/19/how-to-make-a-3d-map-in-blender/#:%7E:text=%20How%20to%20Make%20a%203D%20Map%20in,quality%20until%20the%20final%20images%20are...%20More%20)

For the dynamic data sources, if your sources are GIS service based (WMS/TMS) then they should be able to be consumed via a plugin, and the data sources dynamic (ie: When data updates, the service is publishing updated data).
There is a plugin here
https://gisportal.corp.riotinto.org/portal/home/item.html?id=745b4ddf322d43a29bdc369147a6ae41

Comment: Tahnk you. Then for the dynamic part? I need info to get moving arround the map in real time...

Comment: The hard part will be making sure your data sources are published in a way that is dynamic (ie: Service). ive updated my answer to include more info on dynamic part.